# Animation when adding items to qgraphicsLayout

Tags: qt, qpropertyanimation

In QgraphicsWidget im adding new items (QGraphicsLayoutItem) using Drag/drop on the QGraphicsWidget and using QGraphicsLinearLayout.
If the user wants to move or create the item between the items already present in the layout , i have to animate the movement when the item is inserted between two items like top item moving upwards and the bottom item moving downwards with some time gap.